# How to tile image and put background color in android activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to create this as a background (blue bg with gray grid lines). Except I don't want to use this image since on larger or smaller screens it will stretch the grid lines and it won't look good. So I think the best way is to specify a background color and then draw another image (1x1 transparent tile) and have it tile/repeat. Does anyone know how to specify multiple backgrounds on 1 view in the styles.xml file?

So far I have this:

```
<style name="RegularView" parent="@style/BaseView">
    <item name="android:background">#00112d</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/grid</item>
</style>
```

Also what is a good width size for a single square, I want it so that the squares fit evenly in the width and height of the screen. There shouldn't be like half a square on the last row or column, if that's possible..

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cut small portion of the image, like one square with border and then declare a xml bitmap resource in your `res/drawable` folder.

bitmap_resource.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/small_part_of_image"
    android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

after that just set this file as background in your view. 
It will repeat itself until it fits the whole view.

Comment: Beware that on Android 2 there are some bugs with tileMode using xml. Although workarounds can be easily found and applied.

Comment: @Rolfツ can you be more specific on what bugs there are and what workarounds you are talking about?

Comment: I have no clue this is years ago now, does anyone still use Android 2.X? Or develop apps for that version?